# What is the variable $MYVIMRC?

Tags: vimrc

One of my project folders has a file `$MYVIMRC`. I didn't create it. 
I have a .vimrc file I created in my home folder. What is the difference and what is `$MYVIMRC` and when/how is it created.

Comment: You simply typed an erroneous command at some point or another. You can delete that file safely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`:h $MYVIMRC`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#%24MYVIMRC):

> *VIMINIT* *.vimrc* *_vimrc* *EXINIT* *.exrc* *_exrc* *$MYVIMRC*
>
> c. Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists
>   is used, the others are ignored.  **The $MYVIMRC environment variable is
>   set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set
>   and when using VIMINIT.**
>
> - The environment variable VIMINIT (see also |compatible-default|) (*)
>     The value of $VIMINIT is used as an Ex command line.
> - The environment variable VIMINIT (see also |compatible-default|) (*)
>     The value of $VIMINIT is used as an Ex command line.
> - The user vimrc file(s):
>
>   - "$HOME/.vimrc"    (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
>   - "$HOME/.vim/vimrc"    (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
>   - "s:.vimrc"        (for Amiga) (*)
>   - "home:.vimrc"     (for Amiga) (*)
>   - "home:vimfiles:vimrc"  (for Amiga) (*)
>   - "$VIM/.vimrc"     (for OS/2 and Amiga) (*)
>   - "$HOME/_vimrc"    (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
>   - "$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
>   - "$VIM/_vimrc"     (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)

So basically `$MYVIMRC` contains the location of the file which as used as your configuration file